# global variable not working inside function

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

In a wordpress plugin I have this code

```
 $country_table = $wpdb->prefix . "trackbyid_country";
 $cities_table  = $wpdb->prefix . "trackbyid_cities";
 function database_creation(){
    global $wpdb;
    global $country_table;
    global $cities_table;
    $AO_name = "trackbyid_dbv";
    $AO_value = "1";
    add_option($AO_name, $AO_value);

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $country_table (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        country tinytext NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
    require_once ( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $cities_table(
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
        city tinytext NOT NULL,
        country_id mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        city_latitude mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        city_longitude mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
     dbDelta($sql);


 }
```

I think my problem (Database is not being created) is with global $country_table and $cities_table variables. when I make that variables as local the problem solves! 
whats wrong with my global variable declaration and usage?

Comment: btw you can declare it as `global $wpdb, $country_table, $cities_table;`, no reason to use multiple lines. You also haven't told us exactly what is going wrong in your code, you just say what you think the problem is, we can't read your mind so we don't know the expected vs actual results.

Comment: You really only need the `$wpdb` global, you can declare the other 2 variables inside the function, which is what I would recommend doing in most cases

Comment: `$wpdb->prefix` outside of function, requires `global $wpdb`.

Comment: What is the error? What is the value of `$country_table` if you dump it out?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Topic edited :D thank you, but I need to use this variables many time and I want to declare them once.

Comment: @ArtinArtin Can you share the code for other functions that this calls? such as `dbDelta`

Comment: please learn PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `$country_table` and `$cities_table` won't be defined because you didn't bring in the global $wpdb before you tried to use it in those vars. Try this instead:

```
global $wpdb;
$country_table = $wpdb->prefix . "trackbyid_country";
$cities_table  = $wpdb->prefix . "trackbyid_cities";

function database_creation(){
    global $country_table, $cities_table;

    ...

}
```

Comment: @that true and by correcting `global $country_table, $cities_table;` to `global $country_table, $cities_table, $wpdb;` problem solved